# Implementing Meta Tags for my dynamic links

Tags: flutter, nestjs, deep-linking, meta-tags, api-linkpreview

I have a Flutter app with a NestJs server. My flutter app routes are set up with go_route.

What I am trying to achieve is that when I share links from my app like for example an user (https://mywebsite.com/u/pepe) profile or a post (https://mywebsite.com/p/piufgkmfdkgnkmdfgpe) it will be displayed a preview image in the app where this was shared (whatsapp, x, facebook, etc)

Any help with this guys? No idea from where to start.

No idea from where to start